# Perform aggregation in an array of embedded doc

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database, nosql

```
"employees":[  
      {  
         "empId":100, 
         "Salary":[  
           1000,2000,3000
         ]
   },
   {  
         "empId":101, 
         "Salary":[  
           3000,4000,500
         ]
   }
   ]
```

In the above array, I need to aggregate the salary like 1000+3000,2000+4000 e.t.c and place it in the separate array.

My aggregated result should be :
adding salaries of both empId's
salary[0]+salray[0](empId:100 + empId:101=1000+3000,2000+4000,3000+500)

```
"employees":[  
      {  
         "empId":100, 
         "Salary":[  
           1000,2000,3000
         ]
   },
   {  
         "empId":101, 
         "Salary":[  
           3000,4000,500
         ]
   },
    {  
         "empId":111, 
         "Salary":[  
           4000,6000,3500
         ]
   }
   ]
```

Comment: How would you want the aggregation to be grouped then? Are you looking for the sum of Salary of every empId?

Comment: I had edited my question.Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` all arrays and then group using aggregation framework

```
db.dev777.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$employees"
        }, {
            $unwind : "$employees.Salary"
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$employees.empId",
                salarySum : {
                    $sum : "$employees.Salary"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "_id" : 101.0,
    "salarySum" : 7500.0
},{
    "_id" : 100.0,
    "salarySum" : 6000.0
}
```

***EDIT***

```
db.dev777.aggregate([{
            // transform array to document
            $unwind : "$employees"
        }, {
            // transform array to document and add array index to preserve position info
            $unwind : {
                path : "$employees.Salary",
                includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex"
            }
        },
        {
            $group : {
                // now sum all data by array index field 
                _id : "$arrayIndex",
                salarySum : {
                    $sum : "$employees.Salary"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort : {
                // sort by array index field
                _id : 1
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                // recreate document by pushing back values to an array
                _id : null,
                Salary : {
                    $push : "$salarySum"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                //remove id field and add empID field  
                _id : 0,
                 empID:  {
                    $literal : NumberInt(111)
                },
                Salary : 1
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: I had edited my question.Can anyone please help me out regarding this

Comment: there will be a kind of hard to add this record to current result set. There is a chance to generate sum as requested, but you will get only summary record

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur info

Comment: Hi @profesor79, can you please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366793/how-to-add-arrayindex-position-to-the-unwinded-documents-in-mongo-db-of-version