# How to add arrayIndex position to the unwinded documents in mongo db of version 3.0.4

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Having aggregattion:

```
{
  $unwind:
    {
      path: <field path>,
      includeArrayIndex: <string>,
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: <boolean>
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm using this "$unwind" concept in mongodb version 3.2.It is working fine. But in production I have mongodb version 3.0.4. How can I use this concept in 3.0.4 version ?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to fix it.

1. UPGRADE :-)
2. Change document structure to add a `position` value - it will act as a kind of entryID field - please see snippet below:

Change documnet structure in forEach loop:

```
  db.dev777_copy.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
    var empArraySize = doc.employees.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < empArraySize; i++) {
        var innerArraySize = doc.employees[i].Salary.length;

        for (var j = 0; j < innerArraySize; j++) {
            doc.employees[i].Salary[j] = {
                position : NumberInt(j),
                value : doc.employees[i].Salary[j]
            };
        }

    }
    db.dev777_copy.save(doc);
})
```

and then our document will get new shape:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57862763a63c006944fb508b"),
    "employees" : [{
            "empId" : 100.0,
            "Salary" : [{
                    "position" : 0,
                    "value" : 1000.0
                }, {
                    "position" : 1,
                    "value" : 2000.0
                }, {
                    "position" : 2,
                    "value" : 3000.0
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "empId" : 101.0,
            "Salary" : [{
                    "position" : 0,
                    "value" : 3000.0
                }, {
                    "position" : 1,
                    "value" : 4000.0
                }, {
                    "position" : 2,
                    "value" : 500.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not authorized to  change the datastructure of the document.Can we add arbitrary parameter for storing the position of the arrayindex instead of changing the document structure ?

Comment: no, you need to get collection and process client side

Comment: Then can I use $slice (or) $postion in version 3.0 for getting the array Index postion. Is there any alternative way to do it ?

Comment: Then can you please suggest me some alternatives . I can't upgrade the production db server and I'm not authorized to change the data structure.I'm really stuck over here.

Comment: you need do it clien side

Comment: For that we need to add the position explicitly right ?